# Hostname <URL> was not verified at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpConnection.verifySecureSocketHostname

Tags: java, android, apache, https

I was getting JSON from website's API using HTTP. This is development test URL.

```
public static final String BASE_URL = "http://...."
```

I am using POST request.

```
private Response sendRequest(Request request, boolean debug)
            throws Exception {

        HttpURLConnection conn = null;

        Response response = null;
        long time = 0;

        try {
            conn = (HttpURLConnection) request.getUrl().openConnection();

            if (request.headers != null) {
                for (String header : request.headers.keySet()) {
                    conn.addRequestProperty(header, request.headers.get(header));
                }
            }

            time = System.currentTimeMillis();

            conn.setDoOutput(false);
            if (request instanceof POST) {
                byte[] payload = ((POST) request).body;

                conn.setDoOutput(true);
                conn.setFixedLengthStreamingMode(payload.length);
                conn.getOutputStream().write(payload);//line69
            }

            int status = conn.getResponseCode();

            if (status != HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK)
                response = new Response(status, conn.getResponseMessage()
                        .getBytes());
            else {
                if (conn.getContentType().contains("application/json")) {
                    response = new Response(status, readInputStream(
                            conn.getInputStream()).getBytes());
                } else {
                    response = new Response(status,
                            readInputStreamWithoutUTF8(conn.getInputStream()));
                }

            }
            response.contentType = conn.getContentType();
            response.contentLength = conn.getContentLength();
            response.time = System.currentTimeMillis() - time;
            if (debug)
                dumpRequest(request, response);

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace(System.err);
            throw e;

        } finally {
            if (conn != null)
                conn.disconnect();
        }

        return response;
    }
```

Everything working fine with test URL. But documentation says to use release URL which is

```
public static final String BASE_URL = "https://..."
```

When I changed test URL to release URL, application is giving following exception

> 07-07 11:06:17.515: W/System.err(23000): java.io.IOException: Hostname
>   '...........' was not verified 07-07 11:06:17.515:
>   W/System.err(23000):  at
>   org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpConnection.verifySecureSocketHostname(HttpConnection.java:199)
>   07-07 11:06:17.515: W/System.err(23000):  at
>   org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl$HttpsEngine.makeConnection(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:391)
>   07-07 11:06:17.515: W/System.err(23000):  at
>   org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:205)
>   07-07 11:06:17.515: W/System.err(23000):  at
>   org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:614)
>   07-07 11:06:17.515: W/System.err(23000):  at
>   org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:268)
>   07-07 11:06:17.515: W/System.err(23000):  at
>   com.globalsolutions.mygov.api.rest.SimpleRestClient.sendRequest(SimpleRestClient.java:69)
>   07-07 11:06:17.515: W/System.err(23000):  at
>   com.globalsolutions.mygov.api.rest.SimpleRestClient.post(SimpleRestClient.java:41)
>   07-07 11:06:17.515: W/System.err(23000):  at
>   com.globalsolutions.mygov.api.Api.auth(Api.java:117) 07-07
>   11:06:17.515: W/System.err(23000):    at
>   com.globalsolutions.mygov.ui.SplashActivity$6.run(SplashActivity.java:248)
>   07-07 11:06:17.531: W/System.err(23000):  at
>   java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019) 07-07 11:06:17.531:
>   W/System.err(23000): java.io.IOException: Hostname 'my.gov.uz' was not
>   verified 07-07 11:06:17.539: W/System.err(23000):     at
>   org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpConnection.verifySecureSocketHostname(HttpConnection.java:199)
>   07-07 11:06:17.539: W/System.err(23000):  at
>   org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl$HttpsEngine.makeConnection(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:391)
>   07-07 11:06:17.539: W/System.err(23000):  at
>   org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:205)
>   07-07 11:06:17.539: W/System.err(23000):  at
>   org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:614)
>   07-07 11:06:17.539: W/System.err(23000):  at
>   org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:268)
>   07-07 11:06:17.539: W/System.err(23000):  at
>   com.globalsolutions.mygov.api.rest.SimpleRestClient.sendRequest(SimpleRestClient.java:69)
>   07-07 11:06:17.554: W/System.err(23000):  at
>   com.globalsolutions.mygov.api.rest.SimpleRestClient.post(SimpleRestClient.java:41)
>   07-07 11:06:17.554: W/System.err(23000):  at
>   com.globalsolutions.mygov.api.Api.auth(Api.java:117) 07-07
>   11:06:17.554: W/System.err(23000):    at
>   com.globalsolutions.mygov.ui.SplashActivity$6.run(SplashActivity.java:248)
>   07-07 11:06:17.554: W/System.err(23000):  at
>   java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)

I think this line is causing the error:

```
conn.getOutputStream().write(payload);
```

I googled this exeption, found different suggestions. Honestly, I do not understand how to implement those codes into my application.

Could someone explain how to change HTTP connection to HTTPS connection?
Thank you for your valuable time!

Just in case, I am using Samsung Galaxy Ace with Android 2.3.6

**UPDATE: Updated code using HostnameVerifier**

```
private Response sendRequest(Request request, boolean debug)
            throws Exception {

        HostnameVerifier hostnameVerifier = new HostnameVerifier() {
            @Override
            public boolean verify(String hostname, SSLSession session) {
                HostnameVerifier hv =
                    HttpsURLConnection.getDefaultHostnameVerifier();
                return hv.verify("my.gov.uz", session);
            }
        };

        HttpsURLConnection conn = null;

        Response response = null;
        long time = 0;

        try {

            conn = (HttpsURLConnection) request.getUrl().openConnection();
            conn.setHostnameVerifier(hostnameVerifier);

            if (request.headers != null) {
                for (String header : request.headers.keySet()) {
                    conn.addRequestProperty(header, request.headers.get(header));
                }
            }

            time = System.currentTimeMillis();

            conn.setDoOutput(false);
            if (request instanceof POST) {
                byte[] payload = ((POST) request).body;

                conn.setDoOutput(true);
                conn.setFixedLengthStreamingMode(payload.length);
                conn.getOutputStream().write(payload);
            }

            int status = conn.getResponseCode();

            if (status != HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK)
                response = new Response(status, conn.getResponseMessage()
                        .getBytes());
            else {
                if (conn.getContentType().contains("application/json")) {
                    response = new Response(status, readInputStream(
                            conn.getInputStream()).getBytes());
                } else {
                    response = new Response(status,
                            readInputStreamWithoutUTF8(conn.getInputStream()));
                }

            }
            response.contentType = conn.getContentType();
            response.contentLength = conn.getContentLength();
            response.time = System.currentTimeMillis() - time;
            if (debug)
                dumpRequest(request, response);

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace(System.err);
            throw e;

        } finally {
            if (conn != null)
                conn.disconnect();
        }

        return response;
    }
```

But still getting same exeption:

> 07-07 12:39:30.882: W/System.err(25360): java.io.IOException: Hostname
>   'my.gov.uz' was not verified 07-07 12:39:30.890: W/System.err(25360):
>     at
>   org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpConnection.verifySecureSocketHostname(HttpConnection.java:199)
>   07-07 12:39:30.890: W/System.err(25360):  at
>   org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl$HttpsEngine.makeConnection(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:391)
>   07-07 12:39:30.890: W/System.err(25360):  at
>   org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:205)
>   07-07 12:39:30.890: W/System.err(25360):  at
>   org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:614)
>   07-07 12:39:30.890: W/System.err(25360):  at
>   org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:268)
>   07-07 12:39:30.890: W/System.err(25360):  at
>   com.globalsolutions.mygov.api.rest.SimpleRestClient.sendRequest(SimpleRestClient.java:85)
>   07-07 12:39:30.890: W/System.err(25360):  at
>   com.globalsolutions.mygov.api.rest.SimpleRestClient.post(SimpleRestClient.java:46)
>   07-07 12:39:30.890: W/System.err(25360):  at
>   com.globalsolutions.mygov.api.Api.auth(Api.java:117) 07-07
>   12:39:30.890: W/System.err(25360):    at
>   com.globalsolutions.mygov.ui.SplashActivity$6.run(SplashActivity.java:248)
>   07-07 12:39:30.890: W/System.err(25360):  at
>   java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019) 07-07 12:39:30.898:
>   W/System.err(25360): java.io.IOException: Hostname 'my.gov.uz' was not
>   verified 07-07 12:39:30.898: W/System.err(25360):     at
>   org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpConnection.verifySecureSocketHostname(HttpConnection.java:199)
>   07-07 12:39:30.898: W/System.err(25360):  at
>   org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl$HttpsEngine.makeConnection(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:391)
>   07-07 12:39:30.898: W/System.err(25360):  at
>   org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:205)
>   07-07 12:39:30.898: W/System.err(25360):  at
>   org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:614)
>   07-07 12:39:30.898: W/System.err(25360):  at
>   org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:268)
>   07-07 12:39:30.898: W/System.err(25360):  at
>   com.globalsolutions.mygov.api.rest.SimpleRestClient.sendRequest(SimpleRestClient.java:85)
>   07-07 12:39:30.898: W/System.err(25360):  at
>   com.globalsolutions.mygov.api.rest.SimpleRestClient.post(SimpleRestClient.java:46)
>   07-07 12:39:30.921: W/System.err(25360):  at
>   com.globalsolutions.mygov.api.Api.auth(Api.java:117) 07-07
>   12:39:30.921: W/System.err(25360):    at
>   com.globalsolutions.mygov.ui.SplashActivity$6.run(SplashActivity.java:248)
>   07-07 12:39:30.921: W/System.err(25360):  at
>   java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your server is configured with a certificate that does not have a subject or subject alternative name fields that match the server you are trying to reach. Try [this](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-ssl.html#CommonHostnameProbs) in order to avoid this problem

Comment: I dont have access to server. I have access only from client side. What can I do in this case?

Comment: Have you read the document following the link? It describes how to fix the issue on the client's side. It suggests either using of [HttpsUrlConnection](https://developer.android.com/reference/javax/net/ssl/HttpsURLConnection.html) or use custom [HostnameVerifier](https://developer.android.com/reference/javax/net/ssl/HostnameVerifier.html), just in case [here is the link I was talking about](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-ssl.html#CommonHostnameProbs)

Comment: I have used hostNameVerfier option: HostnameVerifier hostnameVerifier = new HostnameVerifier() {
      @Override
      public boolean verify(String hostname, SSLSession session) {
          HostnameVerifier hv =
              HttpsURLConnection.getDefaultHostnameVerifier();
          return hv.verify("my.gov.uz", session);
      }
  };

  HttpsURLConnection conn = null;

  Response response = null;
  long time = 0;

  try {
   
   conn = (HttpsURLConnection) request.getUrl().openConnection();
   conn.setHostnameVerifier(hostnameVerifier); But it is still giving same exception.

Comment: Actually it's weird, this should be working, are you sure that Exception is the same? Can you please please post the updated code with HostnameVerifier?